# 2nd drive not filling up?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, samba

First of all, i am very new to ubuntu.
I have a laptop running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on which I run Samba to map the network drives on my main computer.

I added a second HDD so I had more storage, I formatted it to EXT4 and mounted it.
everything works fine, until I wanted to store files there, I went to the share on my main PC, transferred a file and thought that it was working fine, until I noticed that the file was on the main drive instead of the 2nd drive.

I've been searching for a couple of hours now but i can't find anything that fixes this.
let me know if there's anything you need

Edit:
The mountpoint i created is /media/Eshare this is where the 2nd drive is mounted to.

my smb.conf to create the share points:

```
[name]
comment = energy samba share
path = /home/energy/energy-share
read only = no
browsable = yes
guest ok = no
[name]
comment = energy2 samba share
path = /media/Eshare/Share
read only = no
browsable = yes
guest ok = no
```

Comment: How are you copying files to that second drive? Can you provide clear examples of commands or a step-by-step if you're using the GUI? As it stands, there's a great deal of ambiguity here 

Comment: hi Matigo, i have 2 samba shares set up, one to the storage on the 1st drive, one to the mountpoint of the second drive. I have both added to my windows PC as a network drive, then i simply drag and drop the files to the network drive i want it to go on

Comment: This is still ambiguous. Could you [edit] your question to include the following details: (1) the mount-point for the new drive (2) the Samba configuration. Without knowing specific details of your setup, any answers will be little more than random guesswork, which is generally a suboptimal means to a solution 

Comment: hi matigo, i have updated the original post to include the 2 details you asked for

Answer (score -1):

i want to start off by saying, i am an idiot. The Hard drive was mounted to /mnt/sda1 instead of /media/Eshare. my bad